# How quickly can we find a value that has large multiplicative order modulo $n$?

Tags: ring-theory, algorithms, asymptotics, intuition, multiplicative-order

If we're trying to find an element modulo $n$ that has multiplicative order at least $\sqrt{n}$, how quickly can we do this?  We don't know if $n$ is prime or composite, only that $n$ definitely has a value with multiplicative order at least $\sqrt{n}$.

I'm interested in both randomized and non-randomized, deterministic algorithms.  I'd like to know the asymptotic bounds for the running time.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: I'd be happy if we could find a non-random, deterministic algorithm that runs in $O(n)$.

Comment: "We don't know if $n$ is prime or composite" - Well, primality checking is polynomial in $\log(n)$, so we might as well assume we know. I have no idea what the answer to your question is, though.